# Query recursiva

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursão

Estou precisando montar uma query recursiva para resolver um simples problema, mas estou com um pouco de dificuldade.

Tenho uma tabela chamada `TABELA1` com os seguintes campos (ID, IDPAI, NOME)

Vou colocar aqui alguns exemplos de registros e o que eu preciso.

Registros na tabela original:

[image: Registros na tabela original]

Como eu consegui fazer com que ficassem através da minha query:

```
USE TESTE
GO

WITH Niveis AS (
                -- Membro âncora
                SELECT Id, IdPai, Nome,
                0 AS Nivel -- nível 0
                FROM TABELA1
                WHERE IdPai IS NULL

                UNION ALL

                -- Filhos
                SELECT T1.Id, T1.IdPai, T1.Nome,
                Nivel+1
                FROM TABELA1 T1
                INNER JOIN Niveis ON T1.IdPai = Niveis.Id
                )
SELECT Id, IdPai, REPLICATE('     ' , Nivel) + Nome AS Nome
FROM Niveis
ORDER BY Id, IdPai
```

[image: Como eu consegui fazer com que ficassem através da minha query]

Como eu necessito:

[image: COMO EU GOSTARIA QUE FICASSEM]

Resultado da query do cigano, chegando perto da solução!

[image: RESULTADO QUERY CIGANO]

Comment: Você pode colocar na sua pergunta como está sua query até então?

Comment: Talvez teria que usar `CASE` e sub-query. Mas acho que isso não seria legal para o tempo de resposta. Talvez no seu código (deve ser c# ou vb) você pode usar uma `array` para agrupar os dados (não tenho como fornecer um exemplo pois não sei que linguagem está a usar)

Comment: Vou usar código C#. Obrigado pela ajuda, já coloquei o código na pergunta. ;-)

Comment: Então @WallaceCarlos pensou em usar um esquema de array para agrupar estes dados, pois como eu disse, acredito que o uso sub-querys para cada "loop" dentro da query pode causar uma pequena demora na entrega dos dados (espero não estar falando bobagem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, me parece só uma questão de ajuste. Apenas concatene o nome do nível anterior com o nível atual de recursão:

```
USE TESTE
GO

WITH Niveis AS (
                -- Membro âncora
                SELECT Id, IdPai, convert(varchar(1000), Nome) as Nome,
                0 AS Nivel -- nível 0
                FROM TABELA1
                WHERE IdPai IS NULL

                UNION ALL

                -- Filhos
                SELECT T1.Id, T1.IdPai, convert(varchar(1000), Niveis.Nome + ' - ' + T1.Nome) as Nome,
                Nivel+1
                FROM TABELA1 T1
                INNER JOIN Niveis ON T1.IdPai = Niveis.Id
                )
SELECT Id, IdPai, Nome
FROM Niveis
ORDER BY Id, IdPai
```

---

**EDIT**

Forcei a tipagem e o nome da coluna para evitar o erro informado por comentário. Também coloquei a conversão com 1000 caracteres para evitar que a coluna fique muito pequena e os níveis não apareçam.

Comment: Cigano, obrigado pela força tmb, mas isso não funciona. 
Dá o seguinte erro:

Os tipos não correspondem entre a âncora e a parte recursiva da coluna "Nome" da consulta recursiva "Niveis"

Comment: @WallaceCarlos Editei a resposta.

Comment: Estamos bem perto da solução meu caro amigo, dá uma olhada no resultado:

1 NULL NIVEL 1
2 1 NIVEL 1 - NIVEL 2
3 2 NIVEL 1 - NIVEL 2 - NIVEL 3
4 3 NIVEL 1 - NIVEL 2 - NIVEL 3 - 
5 4 NIVEL 1 - NIVEL 2 - NIVEL 3 - 
6 NULL QQ COISA
7 NULL OUTRO NIVEL 1
8 7 OUTRO NIVEL 1 - OUTRO NIVEL 2
9 8 OUTRO NIVEL 1 - OUTRO NIVEL 2

Comment: @WallaceCarlos O que falta? Esse comentário ficou desformatado. Não consigo ver a diferença.

Comment: Realmente... Vou colocar lá em cima na pergunta.. 1 min

Comment: Cigano, dá uma olhada no final da pergunta por favor..

Comment: @WallaceCarlos Agora tá bem simples. É só a conversão que ficou pequena. Já editei novamente

Comment: Sensacional.. era exatamente isso meu amigo! Muitíssimo obrigado!!

Comment: @WallaceCarlos Veja aqui como marcar a resposta como aceita: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour. Obrigado!

Comment: Marcada amigo.. eu quem agradeço!! Abs.

Comment: Pessoal, se me permitem eu gostaria de fazer mais uma perguntinha, do jeito que eu havia feito (query da pergunta) a ordenção só funciona caso os ID's sejam crescentes, como eu poderia fazer quando os ID's estiverem fora de ordem crescente nos níveis? Espero que tenham entendido a pergunta. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: @WallaceCarlos Pode fazer outra pergunta, vinculando esta à nova pergunta?

Comment: Posso, mas ainda não sei vincular. To aprendendo a usar a ferramenta. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @WallaceCarlos Só colar o link da pergunta dentro da pergunta ;)

Comment: A tá.. blz... achei que desse pra fazer pela próprio stackoverflow. Flw. Fazendo isso.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52381/ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-query-recursiva... Nova pergunta!