# Ordenação em query recursiva

Tags: sql-server, query, classificação, tsql, recursão

[Em outra pergunta que fiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51862/query-recursiva) eu havia encontrado uma solução porém a ordenação só funciona caso os ID's sejam crescentes:

```
USE TESTE
GO

WITH Niveis AS (
                -- Membro âncora
                SELECT Id, IdPai, convert(varchar(1000), Nome) as Nome,
                0 AS Nivel -- nível 0
                FROM TABELA1
                WHERE IdPai IS NULL

                UNION ALL

                -- Filhos
                SELECT T1.Id, T1.IdPai, convert(varchar(1000), Niveis.Nome + ' - ' + T1.Nome) as Nome,
                Nivel+1
                FROM TABELA1 T1
                INNER JOIN Niveis ON T1.IdPai = Niveis.Id
                )
SELECT Id, IdPai, Nome
FROM Niveis
ORDER BY Id, IdPai
```

Como eu poderia fazer quando os ID's estiverem fora de ordem crescente nos níveis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui uma solução que atendeu as minhas necessidades. Obrigado Cigano, sua ajuda foi de grande valia. Segue o código abaixo caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida.

```
USE TESTE
GO

WITH Niveis AS (
                -- Membro âncora
                SELECT Id, IdPai, convert(varchar(1000), Nome) as Nome,
                0 AS Nivel,
                RANK()  OVER (ORDER BY Id, IdPai) AS Ordem
                FROM TABELA1
                WHERE IdPai IS NULL

                UNION ALL

                -- Filhos
                SELECT T1.Id, T1.IdPai, convert(varchar(1000), Niveis.Nome + ' - ' + T1.Nome) as Nome,
                Nivel+1,
                Ordem
                FROM TABELA1 T1
                INNER JOIN Niveis ON T1.IdPai = Niveis.Id
            )
SELECT Id, IdPai,REPLICATE('     ' , Nivel) + Nome AS Nome, Nome
FROM Niveis
ORDER BY Ordem
```

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, é preciso ter um critério de agrupamento. Vou inventar um. Por exemplo, `GrupoId`.

Tendo isto, basta selecionar pelo `GrupoId` e ordenar ao fim da query conforme abaixo:

```
USE TESTE
GO

WITH Niveis AS (
                -- Membro âncora
                SELECT Id, GrupoId, IdPai, convert(varchar(1000), Nome) as Nome,
                0 AS Nivel -- nível 0
                FROM TABELA1
                WHERE IdPai IS NULL

                UNION ALL

                -- Filhos
                SELECT T1.Id, T1.GrupoId, T1.IdPai, convert(varchar(1000), Niveis.Nome + ' - ' + T1.Nome) as Nome,
                Nivel+1
                FROM TABELA1 T1
                INNER JOIN Niveis ON T1.IdPai = Niveis.Id
            )
SELECT GrupoId, Id, IdPai, Nome
FROM Niveis
ORDER BY GrupoId, Id, IdPai
```