# Como selecionar registros em uma tabela Auto referenciada usando Recursividade?

Tags: sql, sql-server

*Em um cenário de áreas onde uma área pode ser supervisionada por outra é representando em uma estrutura de árvores da seguinte maneira:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Problema:*** Surgiu a necessidade de selecionar a `Área` (**CBT - Complexo Industrial de Cubatão**) mais todas as `Áreas` que seguem a Hierarquia. (Nesta situação todas as Áreas listadas na imagem)

Haverá situações em que a `Área`(**CBT- Gerência de Infraestrutra**) poderá ser solicitado, sendo assim esse seria o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Como deve ser o `select` para selecionar esses dados?

## Tabela Areas:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Areas](
 [IdArea] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [IdAreaPai] [int] NULL,
 [Nome] [varchar](50) NOT NULL)
```

## Inserts:

```
insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
values(null,'CBT - Complexo Industrial de Cubatão')


insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
values(1,'CBT - Áreas Corporativas')

insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
values(2,'CBT - Faturamento')

insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
values(2,'CBT - Gerência de Tecnologia da Informação')

insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
values(2,'CBT - Gerência de Controladoria')

insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
values(2,'CBT - Gerência de Infraestrutura')

insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
values(6,'CBT - Restaurante')

insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
values(6,'CBT - Serviço de infraestrutura')

insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
values(6,'CBT - Transporte')

insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
values(2,'CBT - Gerência de Proj. Correntes Nitrogenados')

insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
values(10,'CBT - Arquivo Técnico')

insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
values(10,'CBT - Proj. Correntes')

insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
values(2,'CBT - Gerência de Recursos Humanos')

 insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
 values(null,'CBT - Complexo')
```

Comment: Deixo-te a ideia de como criar o select, de momento não estou com pc para resolver.:  selecionar todas as 2, por cada resultado, fazer o select where id-pai=id-area e por cada um dos selecionados, juntar o select id-paiSegundoSelect=id-areaPrimeiroSelect.

Comment: @PedroFerreira qualquer ajuda é bem vinda :)

Comment: @Marconi com PC é simples e a linha orientadora também,  para além do link referenciado pelo Henrique, procura por metodologia para iterar um select

Comment: @PedroFerreira obrigado pelas dicas, vou tentar fazer essa query até o final do dia, fique a vontade pra responder também :)

Comment: Semelhante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214625/64969

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu consegui compreender a lógica, mas não entendi porque o select que adicionei na pergunta não funcionou se eu buscar por exemplo por IDArea = 2

Comment: @Marconi assim, eu faria o caso base da recursão diferente, depois poria um `WHERE idAncestral = 2` na parte externa da consulta

Comment: No SQL Fiddle não consegui rodar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Através das perguntas:

- [Resgatar todos os nós de uma árvore do banco de dados SQLite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214625/resgatar-todos-os-n%C3%B3s-de-uma-%C3%A1rvore-do-banco-de-dados-sqlite)
- [Simplest way to do a recursive self-join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757260/simplest-way-to-do-a-recursive-self-join)
- [Query recursiva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51862/query-recursiva)

Consegui chegar ao select abaixo. No meu caso o ponto de parada será a própria `Área.`

```
  WITH hierarquia AS
      ( SELECT *
       FROM Areas
       WHERE IdArea = 6
         UNION ALL
         SELECT t.*
         FROM Areas t
         INNER JOIN hierarquia s ON t.IdAreaPai = s.IdArea )
    SELECT *
    FROM hierarquia
```

## Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se tiver alguém abaixo de "CBT - Restaurante" Eles não virão.

Comment: @JulioSoares adicionei um nível abaixo: `insert into Areas(IdAreaPai, Nome)
values(7,'CBT - Restaurante 2')`e a consulta listou esse dado

Answer (score 1):

Vê se é isso que vc precisa...

```
WITH ArvoreAreas AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        IdArea
        ,IdAreaPai
        ,1 as Level
        ,CAST(Nome as varchar(max)) as Nodes 
        ,IdArea as IdentificadorUnico
    FROM 
        Areas 
    WHERE 
        IdAreaPai is null

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        c.IdArea
        ,c.IdAreaPai
        ,Level + 1
        ,Cast(ac.Nodes + '->' + c.Nome as varchar(max))
        ,c.IdAreaPai as IdentificadorUnico
    FROM 
        Areas c 
        INNER JOIN ArvoreAreas ac ON c.IdAreaPai = ac.IdArea
)
SELECT * FROM ArvoreAreas 
WHERE Nodes like 'CBT - Complexo Industrial de Cubatão%'
ORDER BY Nodes
```

Comment: Seu `Sql` Seleciona a segunda linha dos inserts que adicionei @Julio.

Comment: Editei... Você pode verificar o inicio do campo Nodes.. Lá estará toda a árvore da sua hierarquia

Comment: Julio, não seria melhor usar o id da area de maior hierarquia como condição da consulta raiz da CTE recursiva?

Comment: Depende da hierarquia... Se houver outros níveis abaixo, eles não virão...