# Como verificar o valor na 3ª camada na Firebase com angularfire2?

Tags: firebase, typescript, angular-fire-2

Posso verificar os valores até a segunda camada, quando chega no terceiro lugar onde a matriz de objetos vem, não consigo imprimir o valor da chave "nomeOficina"

Como consigo retornar o valor referente ao nomeOficina?

[image: Print db]

Comment: Não dá pra entender. Você falou uma coisa e postou uma imagem. O que é essa imagem? O que é "terceiro lugar"? O que e como você tentou?

Comment: Seria algo parecido com isto: [Como selecionar registros em uma tabela Auto referenciada usando Recursividade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215916/como-selecionar-registros-em-uma-tabela-auto-referenciada-usando-recursividade)

Comment: Onde você está tentando imprimir este valor? Que mensagem de erro (ou saída) aparece nas tentativas?

Comment: Desculpe pessoal,não expliquei direito,editei,eu so quero retornar o valor da chave nomeOficina para fazer uma comparação,mas nao consigo pois esta no objeto dentro do outro objeto

Comment: Mostre o código que você tentou